# Sharing instance variable between classes

Tags: python, class-design, weak-references

I have two classes A and B and I want to share an instance variable of A to B and make sure that when I call del on the variable in A, B doesn't have access to it anymore and the variable gets properly deleted.

I've had 4 different methods in mind to accomplish this.

1. Inheritance - I decided against this because B isn't an instance of A, and I get issues when calling super (B happens to be a derived class of some other ABC). B also has no use for the other variables and methods defined in A.
2. Nested Classes - I tried this but apparently python nested classes don't behave like C++ one's do.
3. Passing variables - This initially worked as expected but when I called del on the variable in A, B still had access to it beause (I believe) it still had a reference to the variable
4. Global variables - I heard these were bad practice

I know there's probably a solution with `weakref` but I was wondering if there was another solution having to do with program design

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
         self.var = myVar
    def func(self):
         return B(self.myVar2)
    def stop(self):
         del self.myVar
class B():
    def __init__(self, myVar)
        self.myVar2 = myVar
    # Other methods ...
```

Above is an example of passing the variable. When I call stop on an instance of A, the variable doesn't get properly deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a solution using just program design (such as inheritance or nested classes) may be tricky and hard to read but most likely possible.  You could use a global variable but that would be a code smell.  That being said I will add a `weakref` solution here until a different solution is added.

```
import weakref

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Instance of A"

class B:
    """
    Wants a weak reference to an instance of A
    """
    def __init__(self, instance_of_a):
        self._a = weakref.ref(instance_of_a)

    @property
    def a(self):
      return self._a()


a_inst = A()
b_inst = B(a_inst)

print(b_inst.a) # Instance of A
del a_inst
print(b_inst.a) # None
```